# How to search/query/get/sort from ElasticSearch using NEST 1.x with C#

Tags: c#, elasticsearch, nest

I send time for this problem 2 days but can't fix it. Please advise.

```
class Test_Market
    {
        public string x_ric { get; set; }
        public string date { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
        public string rdn_code { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> fids { get; set; }

    }
```

Example JSON in ES.

```
"hits": {
"total": 1,
"max_score": 0.6931472,
"hits": [
{
"_index": "test-market-b",
"_type": "test_market",
"_id": "AWTKqb0e8MENF1jasgCD",
"_score": 0.6931472,
"_source": {
"x_ric": "ABC",
"date": "07-24-2018",
"timestamp": "07-24-2018 05:01:17",
"rdn_code": "XYZ",
"fids": {
"BID": "555",
"ASK": "555",
"BIDSIZE": "555",
"ASKSIZE": "555"
}
}
}
]
}
```

I have no problem about add data to Elasticsearch, but face the issue about sort/query/search.

This code is no problem.

```
var node = new Uri("URL");
var ESsettings = new ConnectionSettings(node);
var client = new ElasticClient(ESsettings);
var response = client.Search<Test_Market>(s => s
                .Index("test-market-b")
                .Type("test_market").Size(10)
                );
```

I can get value of timestamp using

```
var myData = new List<object>();
            foreach (var hit in response.Documents)
            {
                myData.Add(hit.timestamp);
            }
```

Below are I got it no value.

Sorting to find one is the latest timestamp.

```
var responseXX = client.Search<Test_Market>(s => s
                .Index("test-market-b")
                .Type("test_market")
                .Size(1)
                .Sort(sort => sort.OnField( t=>t.timestamp).Descending())

                );
```

Querying

```
            var result = client.Search<Test_Market>(s => s
                .Query(q=>q
                    .Term("date","07-24-2018")
                    )
            );
```

**UPDATED !!!! I can fix this my problem now.
Query AND Sort**

```
var responseXX = client.Search<dynamic>(s => s
               .Query(q => q
                    .Match(m => m.OnField("x_ric").Query("AAA")))
             .Sort(sort => sort.OnField("timestamp").Descending())
                );

            var products = responseXX.Documents.ToList();
```

First of all, post api in ES before insert data into ES.

```
PUT test-market-b
{
  "mappings": {
    "test_market": {
      "properties": {
        "date": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "MM-dd-yyyy"
        },
        "timestamp": {
          "type":   "date",
          "format": "MM-dd-yyyy HH:mm:ss"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: The `timestamp` field should not be of type `string` but `date` instead.

Comment: @Val I tried .Query(q=>q.Term("date","07-24-2018") or .Query(q=>q.Term("x_ric","ABC") They give me no value.

Comment: I meant in your `Test_Market` class, `timestamp` should be defined as a date and not as a string

Comment: Check out the docs for 1.x: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/net-api/1.x/index.html